# Update dynamic field django queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i want build update  django `queryset` with dynamic field like param.
Example my field is `planned`:

```
 def update_data(period, old_planned, new_planned):
    Cost.objects.filter(period=period).update(
            planned=F('planned') - old_planned + new_planned)
```

If i want pass `planned` field like param input in `def` like `def(period, old_planned, new_planned, update_field)`, how to do it with keep use `F` inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assumption

1. The filtering process is always against the **`period`** field

#### Changes

For the sake of generalization, I've added one extra argument, **`param_value`** and changed `old_planned` to **`old_param_value`** and `new_planned` to **`new_param_value`**

#### Code Sample

```
def update_data(period, param_value, old_param_value, new_param_value):
    update_kwargs = {param_value:F(param_value) - old_param_value + new_param_value}
    Cost.objects.filter(period=period).update(**update_kwargs)
```

Comment: ty , i will try